# Use Html file as template in nodejs for sending emails for marketing with some complex level data

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I want to use Html file as template in **nodejs** for sending emails for marketing with some complex level data like graphs populating them dynamically and also show grids etc. I want that to be dynamic like for each user the data can vary.
what is the best possible way to do this
I want this on server side with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you should check out using EJS templates with express. EJS embeds javascript in html to create dynamic content.

Checkout a tutorial [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

Comment: this looks exactly what I was searching. but I will only mark it correct when I will use it hopefully tomorrow

Comment: your link helped me and it is working fine I am using it like charm . I used ejs = require(ejs) and then ejs.render.... function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the email-templates package. The implementation is quite easy. In the case you use nodemailer you'll first need to configure the transport variable just like this (Example with mailtrap):

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
      port: 465,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: // mailtrap.io username
        pass: // mailtrap.io password
      }
    });
```

Then you use the package creating the email and sending it with the variables you need using the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates). For example:

```
const email = new Email({
      transport: transporter,
      send: true,
      preview: false,
      views: {
        options: {
          extension: 'ejs', //or hbs or whatever template you use
        },
        root: 'path/to/email/templates',
      },
    });

email.send({
      template: 'hello',
      message: {
        from: 'Daenerys Targaryen <no-reply@example.com>',
        to: 'john@snow.com',
      },
      locals: {
        fname: 'John',
        lname: 'Snow',
      },
    }).then(() => console.log('email has been send!'));
```

In this case you'll have a file inside `email/templates` called `hello.ejs` with the variables `fname` and `lname` (In your case you'll use the user data). For more examples and cases go to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates)

Comment: what if I want to loop over the data and also use partial views inside main view
I think this suits more to my scenario

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: Oh I didn't know what template you was using so I didn't take it for granted. You can put the whole email stuf inside the loop, in that way it sends the email for each user with the correspondant data.